# Cheapest way to produce 200-1000 pieces of 0.2 mm copper plates

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, electromagnetism

I want to build a strong electro magnet. I came to the conclusion that the smartest arrangement would be something like hundreds of thin sheets of 0.2 mm copper with PTFE isolation. This reduces resistance (diameter) and allows maximally compact stacking.

I struggle a little bit, because actually no one seems to produce something like this. Instead industry prefers wires, even if they are not compact enough to get a good performance.

Question is: What is the smartest, cheapest and easiest way to get sheets like in the image below? Diameter would be around 4 to 8 cm.

[image]

Comment: Waterjet cutting

Comment: Even if the copper is just 0.2 mm thick?

Comment: Yes. Or laser cutting. The alternative is stamping/die cutting. You will need to invest in the tool whereas waterjet or laser has no tooling costs

Comment: Is a CO2 laser suitable or is there too much reflection.

Comment: Likely a fiber laser will be more suitable. Common in commercial/industrial grade equipment.

Comment: Joe Pi has done a video where he makes very thin washers/shims using his lathe, it might get you part way there.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGsA_q4guwM  The two smaller holes could be done using a dremel clamped in a lathe toolpost while the stack of parts is still in the lathe chuck.

Answer (score 1):

Your "best" options would be waterjet or laser cutting as long as the cutting tolerances are acceptable for your design. There are virtually no tooling costs. You can make a 2D cad drawing and get multiple quotes very quickly for this type of manufacturing.

Otherwise, continuous die cutting/stamping from a foil roll would be more suited for high volume, higher precision manufacturing.

Comment: This is how id do it. Just slap it on a sacraficial board and cut it with the waterjet. hour later enough for a few days of assembly. Though to be honest a fiberlaser would be better, but i dont have one available. Note that die cutting isnt nesseserily all that expensive either, even for the tool.